# Pythagorean Triple Printing Issue

Tags: c, pythagorean

Just an understanding of what I'm doing: we're setting a maxbound for "x" and then listing all the primitive pythagorean triples. I'm getting an error for my gcd line and if statement line as well. Any guidance would help thoroughly, thanks guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
  int x,y,z;
  int a,b,c;
  int max;

  //Get user input
  printf("What is the maximum bound on x?\n");
  scanf("%d", &max);

  y = 1;
  while (y < x) {

    while (x <= max) {

      if ((x%2 == 1 || y%2 == 1) && gcd(x, y) == 1) {
        return x;
      }
      else {
        a = (x*x)-(y*y);
        b = 2*x*y;
        c = (x*x)+(y*y);
      }
      printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", a, b, c);
      x++;
      y++;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a gcd function defined? What error are you getting?

Comment: How is this a "triple printing issue"?

Comment: I'm receiving an implicit declaration of function 'gcd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems with your code:

- You are comparing `y` with `x` in `while (y < x)` with `x` uninitialized. I guess you need all pairs of `x, y` with `y < x <= max`.
- When you `return` you exit the program. I guess you need to check if `x`, `y` are coprimes (`gcd(x, y) == 1`) and have an odd difference (`(x - y) % 2 == 1`) for generating a primitive triple.
- You are not defining `gcd`.

So you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(x, y) {
    return y == 0 ? x : gcd(y, x % y);
}

int main () {
  int x, y, max;
  printf("Maximum x? ");
  scanf("%d", &max);

  for (x = 2; x <= max; x++)
    for (y = 1; y < x; y++)
      if (((x - y) % 2 == 1) && (gcd(x, y) == 1))
        printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", x * x - y * y, 2 * x * y, x * x + y * y);
}
```

Comment: Ok last try with newer version?